# Is there any way to remove headers from org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl?

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle

In my app headers are taking 5Mb+ of retained space in JVM. I was wondering if there is any way to clean them up after osgi bundle initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the headers can be queried at runtime, so they cannot be "cleaned up". Your best bet is to strip out any headers you don't need yourself and repackage the bundle(s). 5MB+ does sound like a lot!

Comment: Thanks! What do you think about interning them so they are in metaspace instead of old gen? I simply want to cut gc times (and every megabyte counts).

Comment: I'm not sure how you would do that from a coding point of view, given that they need to be read from the manifest initially and somehow restored from a persisted file on restart. If you know a way to achieve that, I'm sure the community would be glad to review a patch... That said, it still sounds like you could strip some headers yourself.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Indeed I have control over header generation but application is 10 years and I don't know how removing headers in one place will affect all modules. For now I'll leave that as is and will keep 'big headers' problem in the back of my mind.